# for loop to check multiple var to return the name of empty var

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, var

i'm writing a bash script, i have a list of var

```
var1="chicken"
var2="sweet potatoe"
var3=""
var4="rice"
```

And i want to return the name of the var itself which is empty

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    if [[ ! -n "$var" ]]; then
    echo "Fix that: $var ${!var}"
    fi
done
```

this return nothing.

the opposite works

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    if [[ -n "$var" ]]; then
    echo "Fix that: $var ${!var}"
    fi
done
```

I have tested several way to achieve this, i want to keep it very simple, i can't figure it out.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use variable indirection:

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 var4; do
    [[ -z ${!var} ]] && echo empty: $var
done
```

```
empty: var3
```

Comment: OP is bad luck, since already used the indirect expansion of `${!var}`, maybe not fully understand the meaning of it. refer here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html